# How do I get the user location for the Google Places API Place Picker to work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, apple-watch, google-maps-sdk-ios

At the most recent Google IO, they released the Google Places API for iOS. I'm having trouble, though, when the location used to pick places isn't hard coded. I want to find places nearby with the Place Picker. 
Here's a screenshot of how the current location isn't picked up:
[image: Google Places API Place Picker]
Here's my code:
FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

//<GMSMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *address2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cat;

//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lat;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lon;
//
@property double latitude;
@property double longitude;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *catLabel;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController {
    GMSPlacePicker *_placePicker;
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager
//    locationManager.delegate = self; // we set the delegate of locationManager to self.
//    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // setting the accuracy
//    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
//
//    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  //requesting location updates

    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView_.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"User's location: %@", mapView_.myLocation);

}


//
//-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
//    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error retrieving your location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
//    [errorAlert show];
//    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);
//}
//-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
//{
//    CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
//    _lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
//    _lon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
//    double _latitude = [_lat doubleValue];
//    double _longitude = [_lon doubleValue];
//}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//- (NSString *)deviceLocation
//{
//    NSString *theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
//    return theLocation;
//}



// Add a UIButton in Interface Builder to call this function
- (IBAction)pickPlace:(UIButton *)sender {

    CLLocation *myLocation = mapView_.myLocation;

//    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.788204, -122.411937);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001,
                                                                  center.longitude + 0.001);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001,
                                                             center.longitude - 0.001);
    GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast
                                                                         coordinate:southWest];
    GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:viewport];
    _placePicker = [[GMSPlacePicker alloc] initWithConfig:config];

    [_placePicker pickPlaceWithCallback:^(GMSPlace *place, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Pick Place error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        if (place != nil) {
            _name2 = place.name;
            NSLog(place.name);
            self.nameLabel.text = place.name;
            _address2 = place.formattedAddress;
            self.addressLabel.text = [[place.formattedAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@", "]
                                  componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];;
            NSLog(place.formattedAddress);


            _cat = place.types[0];
            self.catLabel.text = place.types[0];
            NSLog(_cat);

        } else {
            _name2 = @"No place selected";
            _address2 = @"";
        }
    }];
}



- (void)requestAlwaysAuthorization
{
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    // If the status is denied or only granted for when in use, display an alert
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSString *title;
        title = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ? @"Location services are off" : @"Background location is not enabled";
        NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    // The user has not enabled any location services. Request background authorization.
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}

@end
```

Also, is there any way I can use the place picker for the apple watch? Thanks!

Comment: sorry what's your problem again? You code doesn't compile?

Comment: it doesn't pick up the current user location.

Comment: you mean `CLLocation *myLocation = mapView_.myLocation;` doesn't have user coordinates?

Comment: That's correct, I just put the NSLog to get the location under that line of code and got this:  User's location: (null)

Comment: are you initializing `mapView_`?

Comment: I looked it up, am I supposed to do this: mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];? Keep in mind that the map is invisible until place picker comes up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80903/discussion-between-meghan66-and-lead-the-zeppelin).

Comment: This code is working for you? Can you please send this code available site link.I want to integrate same as this to my application

Answer (score 0):

By adding Core Location to the app I was able to get the coordinates for current location to be used in the place picker. Here's my code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GMSPlacePickerConfig *config = [[GMSPlacePickerConfig alloc] initWithViewport:nil];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid code-only answers. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer